# Something like this, login to sharepoint by code and url, is it possible?

Tags: login, custom-login-page

We need a page to get query string and if it is true, set sharepoint login session and then redirect it to sharepoint homepage. (login user to sharepoint by url)

I simulate what we want in PHP language: (session name and get name is not real)

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    header("Location: sharepoint homepage");
    exit;
}

if (!isset($_GET['uid'])) die("Invalid Uid!");

$uid = (int) $_GET['uid'];

$_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;

header("Location: sharepoint homepage");

?>
```

Is it possible do this by ASP.NET and sharepoint?

What is logged user session or cookie data?